# Autocomplete not working after jQuery/jQueryUI upgrade

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

After the upgrade of jQuery and jQueryUI, the autocomplete part is throwing an error:

> SCRIPT5007: Object expected

Here is the code:

```
(function($) {

$.widget("ui.fwcomplete", {

    // default options
    options: {
        baseUrl: "${querycompletion.base.url}",
        searchUrl: "",
        format: "opensearch",
        collection: "",
        highlight: false,
        minLength: 2,
        hlPre: "<b>",
        hlPost: "</b>",
        withNumbers: false,
        dataType: "jsonp"
    },
    _open: false,
    _enabled: true,

    _create: function() {
        var self = this;
        this.element.autocomplete({
            source: function(request, fn) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: self.options.baseUrl + "/complete.do",
                    dataType: self.options.dataType,
                    data: {
                        format: self.options.format,
                        q: request.term,
                        c: self.options.collection
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        if ($.isArray(data) && "opensearch" == self.options.format) {
                            fn(self._responseOpenSearch(data, request.term));

                        } else if ($.isPlainObject(data) && "json" == self.options.format) {
                            fn(self._responseJSON(data, request.term));
                        }
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: this.options.minLength,
            select: function(event, ui) {
            var url = self.options.searchUrl == "" ? window.location.toString().split('?')[0] : self.options.searchUrl;
                url += "?q=" + ui.item.value;
                if (getURLParameter('sp') != 'null')
                    url += "&sp=" + getURLParameter('sp');
                window.location = url;
            },
            open: function(event, ui) {
                self._open = true;
            },
            close: function(event, ui) {
                self._open = false;
            }
        });
    },

    _responseOpenSearch: function(data, term, fn) {
        return this._unique(data[1]);
    },

    _responseJSON: function(data, term) {
        if (this.options.highlight) {
            data = this._highlight(data, term);

            if (!$.isEmptyObject(data[0])) {
                return this._unique(data);
            }
            return data;
        } else {
            return this._unique(data.suggestions[0].suggestions);
        }
    },

    _highlight: function(data, term) {
        var termregex = new RegExp("(" + term + ")", "i"),
            self = this,
            res = [];
        $(data.suggestions).each(function() {
            $(this.suggestions).each(function() {
                this.label = this.label || this.value;
                this.value = this.value || this.label;
                this.label = this.label.replace(termregex, self.options.hlPre + "$1" + self.options.hlPost);

                if (self.options.withNumbers && this.hits) {
                    this.label = this.label + " (" + this.hits + ")";
                }
                res.push({
                    label: this.label,
                    value: this.value
                });
            });
        });
        return res;
    },

    _unique: function(arr) {
        var unique = [];
        outer: for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
            for (var j = 0, len2 = unique.length; j < len2; j++) {
                if ($.isPlainObject(arr[i]) && unique[j].label == arr[i].label) {
                    continue outer;
                } else if (unique[j] == arr[i]) {
                    continue outer;
                }
            }
            unique.push(arr[i]);
        }
        return unique;
    },

    _setOption: function(key) {
        this.element.autocomplete("option", arguments[0], arguments[1]);
        $.Widget.prototype._setOption.apply(this, arguments);
    },

    isOpen: function() {
        return this._open;
    },

    open: function() {
        this.element.autocomplete("open");
    },

    close: function() {
        this.element.autocomplete("close");
    },

    enable: function() {
        this.element.autocomplete("enable");
        this._enabled = true;
    },

    isEnabled: function() {
        return this._enabled;
    },

    disable: function() {
        this.element.autocomplete("disable");
        this._enabled = false;
    },

    destroy: function() {
        this.element.autocomplete("destroy");
        $.Widget.prototype.destroy.apply(this, arguments);
    }
});
} (jQuery));


// Replace the functionality of the jQuery autocomplete widget to
// allow inserting HTML labels rather than text-only.
(function( $ ) {
$(function() {
    $.extend($.ui.autocomplete.prototype, {
        _renderItem_orig: $.ui.autocomplete.prototype._renderItem,
        _response_orig: $.ui.autocomplete.prototype._response,

        _renderItem: function( ul, item) {
            return $( "<li></li>" )
                .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
                .append( "<a>" + item.label + "</a>" )
                .appendTo( ul );
        },

        _response: function( content ) {
            if ( !this.options.disabled && content && content.length ) {
                    content = this._normalize( content );
                    this._suggest( content );
                    this._trigger( "open" );
            } else {
                    this.close();
            }
            this.element.removeClass( "ui-autocomplete-loading" );
        }
    });
});
})(jQuery)
```

When debugging I get to this line of code:

```
fn(self._responseJSON(data, request.term));
```

which throws that exception right back at me and I can see that the "fn" is undefined.
What am I doing wrong here?
I hope that there is someone who can figure this out, I've lost it. :(

Comment: _response is not returning a value, (compare to original)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand? Do you mean _responseJSON? But it's "fn" that's undefined, "self._responseJSON(data, request.term)" returns an array of strings.

Comment: When you "Replace the functionality..." the old function _response, ($.ui.autocomplete.prototype._response), returned a value (return ... r.apply(this,arguments)

Comment: When you "Replace the functionality..." one of the functions you replace, _response, ($.ui.autocomplete.prototype._response), returned a value, the function you replace it with does not return anything. I suspect this is the origin of the problem.

Comment: Problem is that I only upgraded the jQuery UI from version 1.9.2 to 1.10.1 and the jQuery from version 1.4.2 to 1.9.1 and after that it stopped working. Has something changed regarding this in the versions of jQuery and jQueryUI?

Comment: It's exciting to see code I've authored being used. I hope it's not giving you too much of an headache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Autocomplete version 1.8.18, note there is no return value:-

```
_response: function( content ) {
    if ( !this.options.disabled && content && content.length ) {
        content = this._normalize( content );
        this._suggest( content );
        this._trigger( "open" );
    } else {
        this.close();
    }
    this.pending--;
    if ( !this.pending ) {
        this.element.removeClass( "ui-autocomplete-loading" );
    }
}
```

Autocomplete version 1.10.1 (latest)

```
_response: function() {
    var that = this,
        index = ++requestIndex;

    return function( content ) {
        if ( index === requestIndex ) {
            that.__response( content );
        }

        that.pending--;
        if ( !that.pending ) {
            that.element.removeClass( "ui-autocomplete-loading" );
        }
    };
},

__response: function( content ) {
    if ( content ) {
        content = this._normalize( content );
    }
    this._trigger( "response", null, { content: content } );
    if ( !this.options.disabled && content && content.length && !this.cancelSearch ) {
        this._suggest( content );
        this._trigger( "open" );
    } else {
        // use ._close() instead of .close() so we don't cancel future searches
        this._close();
    }
}
```

You are overriding _response but this function now requires a return value, it looks like you should now be overriding _response and also __response

Comment: Great, that's it. Actually, I ddin't had to override the _response at all, so I just removed the override part and it worked. Thanks mate! ;)